# mathjs eval error: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function

Tags: javascript, eval, mathjs

If I run a code:

```
    obj = {};
    obj['number'] = 1;
    obj['expressionS'] = 'Sin(0.5 * c1)';
    obj['compiledExpressionS'] = null;

    let cnr = 'c' + obj.number;
    let params = {};
    params[cnr] = 2;

    var parsedExpressionS = math.parse(obj.expressionS);
    obj.compiledExpressionS = parsedExpressionS.compile();
    let value = obj.compiledExpressionS.eval(params);
```

I will get an error (thrown in last line):
**(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function**. Mathjs library is used here (docs:  http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html ). I have no idea why the error apear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not complied the value ,

```
obj.compiledExpressionS = parsedExpressionS.compile(math);
```

and that `Sin` should be lower case

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/oxb3sp5o/414/

Working code

```
obj = {};
obj['number'] = 1;
obj['expressionS'] = 'sin(0.5 * c1)';
obj['compiledExpressionS'] = null;

let cnr = 'c' + obj.number;
let params = {};
params[cnr] = 2;

var parsedExpressionS = math.parse(obj.expressionS);
obj.compiledExpressionS = parsedExpressionS.compile(math);
let value = obj.compiledExpressionS.eval(params);
console.log(value);
```